# Prevent Voice over announcement again before changing UIAccessibility focus to other element

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, accessibility, voiceover

I have a View . On double tap action I am hiding it . 
But before posting to other view it announces once again .
Below is code snippet.

```
func setUpAccessibility() {
                    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(blockLabelViewSwipeGesture))
                    blockContainerView.accessibilityLabel = "Some text label"
                    blockContainerView.accessibilityHint = "Double tap to dismiss"
                    blockContainerView.isAccessibilityElement = true
                    blockContainerView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}

    @objc private func blockLabelViewSwipeGesture(_ gestureRecognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer { 
             UIAccessibility.post(notification: .layoutChanged, argument: self.headerView)
            //Dismiss view 
            ///DO some work
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue . In action method we need to set  accessibilityLabel to empty and if accessibilityHint is there then set it to empty sting .
Below is code snippet .

```
 @objc private func blockLabelViewSwipeGesture(_ gestureRecognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer { 
            blockContainerView.isAccessibilityElement = false
            blockContainerView.accessibilityLabel = ""
            blockContainerView.accessibilityHint = ""

           UIAccessibility.post(notification: .layoutChanged, argument: self.headerView)
            //Dismiss view 
            ///DO some work
}
```